# Why does Haskell's bracket function work in executables but fail to clean up in tests?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm seeing a very strange behavior where Haskell's `bracket` function is behaving differently depending on whether `stack run` or `stack test` is used.

Consider the following code, where two nested brackets are used to create and clean up Docker containers:

```hs
module Main where

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Exception
import System.Process

main :: IO ()
main = do
  bracket (callProcess "docker" ["run", "-d", "--name", "container1", "registry:2"])
          (\() -> do
              putStrLn "Outer release"
              callProcess "docker" ["rm", "-f", "container1"]
              putStrLn "Done with outer release"
          )
          (\() -> do
             bracket (callProcess "docker" ["run", "-d", "--name", "container2", "registry:2"])
                     (\() -> do
                         putStrLn "Inner release"
                         callProcess "docker" ["rm", "-f", "container2"]
                         putStrLn "Done with inner release"
                     )
                     (\() -> do
                         putStrLn "Inside both brackets, sleeping!"
                         threadDelay 300000000
                     )
          )
```

When I run this with `stack run` and interrupt with `Ctrl+C`, I get the expected output:

```
Inside both brackets, sleeping!
^CInner release
container2
Done with inner release
Outer release
container1
Done with outer release
```

And I can verify that both Docker containers are created and then removed.

However, if I paste this exact same code into a test and run `stack test`, only (part of) the first cleanup happens:

```
Inside both brackets, sleeping!
^CInner release
container2
```

This results in a Docker container left running on my machine. What's going on?

- I've made sure that the exact same `ghc-options` are passed to both.
- Full demonstration repo here: https://github.com/thomasjm/bracket-issue

Comment: Does stack test use threads?

Comment: I'm not sure. I noticed one interesting fact: if I dig up the actual compiled test executable under `.stack-work` and run it directly, then the problem doesn't happen. It only happens when running under `stack test`.

Comment: I can guess what's going on, but I don't use stack at all. It's just a guess based on behavior. 1) `stack test` starts worker threads to handle tests. 2) the SIGINT handler kills the main thread. 3) Haskell programs terminate when the main thread does, ignoring any additional threads. 2 is the default behavior on SIGINT for programs compiled by GHC. 3 is how threads work in Haskell. 1 is a complete guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `stack run`, Stack effectively uses an `exec` system call to transfer control to the executable, so the process for the new executable replaces the running Stack process, much as if you'd run the executable directly from the shell.  Here's what the process tree looks like after `stack run`.  Note in particular that the executable is a direct child of the Bash shell.  More critically, note that the terminal's foreground process group (TPGID) is 17996, and the only process in that process group (PGID) is the `bracket-test-exe` process.

```
PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
13816 13831 13831 13831 pts/3    17996 Ss    2001   0:00  |       \_ /bin/bash --noediting -i
13831 17996 17996 13831 pts/3    17996 Sl+   2001   0:00  |       |   \_ .../.stack-work/.../bracket-test-exe
```

As a result, when you press Ctrl-C to interrupt the process running either under `stack run` or directly from the shell, the SIGINT signal is delivered only to the `bracket-test-exe` process.  This raises an asynchronous `UserInterrupt` exception.  The way `bracket` works, when:

```
bracket
  acquire
  (\() -> release)
  (\() -> body)
```

receives an asynchronous exception while processing `body`, it runs `release` and then re-raises the exception.  With your nested `bracket` calls, this has the effect of interrupting the inner body, processing the inner release, re-raising the exception to interrupt the outer body, and processing the outer release, and finally re-raising the exception to terminate the program.  (If there were more actions following the outer `bracket` in your `main` function, they wouldn't be executed.)

On the other hand, when you use `stack test`, Stack uses `withProcessWait` to launch the executable as a child process of the `stack test` process.  In the following process tree, note that `bracket-test-test` is a child process of `stack test`.  Critically, the terminal's foreground process group is 18050, and that process group includes both the `stack test` process and the `bracket-test-test` process.

```
PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
13816 13831 13831 13831 pts/3    18050 Ss    2001   0:00  |       \_ /bin/bash --noediting -i
13831 18050 18050 13831 pts/3    18050 Sl+   2001   0:00  |       |   \_ stack test
18050 18060 18050 13831 pts/3    18050 Sl+   2001   0:00  |       |       \_ .../.stack-work/.../bracket-test-test
```

When you hit Ctrl-C in the terminal, the SIGINT signal is sent to *all* processes in the terminal's foreground process group so both `stack test` and `bracket-test-test` get the signal.  `bracket-test-test` will start processing the signal and running finalizers as described above.  However, there's a race condition here because when `stack test` is interrupted, it's in the middle of `withProcessWait` which is defined more or less as follows:

```
withProcessWait config f =
  bracket
    (startProcess config)
    stopProcess
    (\p -> f p <* waitExitCode p)
```

so, when its `bracket` is interrupted, it calls `stopProcess` which terminates the child process by sending it the `SIGTERM` signal.  In constrast to `SIGINT`, this doesn't raise an asynchronous exception.  It just terminates the child immediately, generally before it can finish running any finalizers.

I can't think of a particularly easy way to work around this.  One way is to use the facilities in `System.Posix` to put the process into its own process group:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- save old terminal foreground process group
  oldpgid <- getTerminalProcessGroupID (Fd 2)
  -- get our PID
  mypid <- getProcessID
  let -- put us in our own foreground process group
      handleInt  = setTerminalProcessGroupID (Fd 2) mypid >> createProcessGroupFor mypid
      -- restore the old foreground process gorup
      releaseInt = setTerminalProcessGroupID (Fd 2) oldpgid
  bracket
    (handleInt >> putStrLn "acquire")
    (\() -> threadDelay 1000000 >> putStrLn "release" >> releaseInt)
    (\() -> putStrLn "between" >> threadDelay 60000000)
  putStrLn "finished"
```

Now, Ctrl-C will result in SIGINT being delivered only to the `bracket-test-test` process.  It'll clean up, restore the original foreground process group to point to the `stack test` process, and terminate.  This will result in the test failing, and `stack test` will just keep running.

An alternative would be to try to handle the `SIGTERM` and keep the child process running to perform cleanup, even once the `stack test` process has terminated.  This is kind of ugly since the process will kind of be cleaning up in the background while you're looking at the shell prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! FYI I filed a Stack bug about this here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/5144. It seems like the real fix would be for `stack test` to launch processes with the `delegate_ctlc` option from `System.Process` (or something similar).